# If $Q$ is prime ideal of $S$, show that $f^{-1}(Q)$ is a prime ideal of $R$

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $f:R \rightarrow S$ be a surjective ring homomorphism. If $Q$ is prime ideal of $S$, show that $f^{-1}(Q)$ is a prime ideal of $R$.

Suppose $f^{-1}(x),f^{-1}(y) \in f^{-1}(Q)$ where $x,y \in Q$. Then I want to show that $f^{-1}(x)-f^{-1}(y) \in f^{-1}(Q)$

Notice that $f(f^{-1}(x)-f^{-1}(y))=ff^{-1}(x)-ff^{-1}(y)=x-y \in Q$ because $Q$ is an ideal. Is this correct?

Comment: The main glitch in your work that I did not mention in my answer is that $f$ is not necessarily injective, so $f^{-1}(x)$ and $f^{-1}(y)$ are not single elements; rather they are sets. We simply cannot prove that $f^{-1}(Q)$ is a subgroup of $R$ in this way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that we do not need $f$ to be surjective.

You are looking at it somewhat backwards. You need to show that when $r,s\in R$ are preimages of elements of $Q$ (i.e. they satisfy $f(x),f(y)\in Q$), then $f(r-s)\in Q$. This verifies $r-s\in f^{-1}(Q)$.

Similarly, you want to show that if $r\in f^{-1}(Q)$ and $x\in R$, then $xr\in f^{-1}(Q)$. I.e., that $f(xr)\in Q$. This verifies $f^{-1}(Q)$ is a left ideal, and verifying that it is also a right ideal is done in the same way.

So $f^{-1}(Q)$ is an ideal. To show that it is prime, consider the condition that an ideal is prime and verify that it holds for $f^{-1}(Q)$ in the same way as we worked above.

Answer (score 1):

Let us assume that $x, y \in f^{-1}(Q)$.  By definition, this means that $f(x), f(y) \in Q$.  Thus $f(x-y) = f(x) - f(y) \in Q$ because $Q$ is an ideal (and, in particular, an additive subgroup of $S$).  By the definition of $f^{-1}(Q)$ again, we conclude that $x - y \in f^{-1}(Q)$, as desired.